# Parse a date in JAVA

Tags: java, date, parsing

I have a date as a String "20161006133408" in the format "yyyyMMddhhmmss". So I make things like:

```
DateFormat dfmt2 = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMddhhmmss" );
dfmt2.setLenient(false);

try {
    Date d = dfmt2.parse(updateTimeDate);
} catch{...}
```

And I get the following Exception at the line where I parse:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20161006133408"
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Put `HH` for hours instead of `hh` ( `h`: Hour in am/pm (1-12)  `H`: Hour in day (0-23)).

Comment: I wonder what you have though when you passed "13" into a pattern which expects at most "12" as the hour. And I wonder why you don't care about reading the documentation.

Comment: You wonder too much.

Comment: That's right, you're just lazy. That's you asked others to do your research :).

Answer (score 0):

Use HH for hours instead. HH takes 24-hour, hh takes 1-12 (am/pm).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Was about to post the same. Pozdrawiam!

Comment: Answering a Question with dozens of duplicates is not helpful.